# Writing comments in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I want to explain my model step by step so anyone can easely understand what's going on.

So, is it possible to write comments in the QGIS's Graphical Modeler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the help text editor (button next to green "play" button) to edit informational metadata with your model:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Do you know if it is possible to change the headings? For example "Algorithm description" to something else.

Comment: No, these seem to be fixed within QGIS. I tried adding an extra item to the saved model XML file but it was not read or shown in the dialog. If you really want this then make a QGIS feature request.